# How to solve svn --force rm 

Tags: svn

So you have a directory with a file

```
dir/myfile
```

`dir` is inside a svn folder and you do

```
svn add dir

svn --force rm dir/.*
```

You were trying to not add some `.something` files but you did it the wrong way.
You now do `ls` and `dir` is no there. You have a problem. You still have a copy of `myfile`, so you do:

```
mkdir newdir
cd newdir
cp fromsomeplace/myfile .
svn add .
```

But no. svn complains that newdir is scheduled to be removed.

Note this:

```
$ svn status
D    .
```

Answer (score 0):

how about reverting to the pristine working copy you started with?

```
svn revert dir
```

or maybe

```
svn revert newdir
```

and then start over (you say you have a copy of myfile anyway.)